# How to fix the BotError about Adaptive Cards Tab?

Tags: botframework

I want to enable SSO for Adaptive Cards Tab following the SSO pattern for message extensions.

And the type of interface TabResponsePayload includes "silentAuth".
refer to the url: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botframework-schema/src/teams/index.ts#L1352
`type?: "continue" | "auth" | "silentAuth"`

In `handleTeamsTabFetch`, I return the tabResponse:

```
{
            tab: {
                type: "silentAuth",
                suggestedActions: {
                    actions: [
                        {
                            type: "openUrl",
                            value: signInLink,
                            title: "Sign in to this app"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
    }
```

However, when I was debugging in Microsoft Teams, the error occurred:
{"errorCode":1008,"message":"Error when processing invoke response: Tab response type (silentAuth) from bot is not supported"}

Does anyone know what's going on here?